# mui Grid items not fit Grid container

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, flexbox

I'm having a hard time to fit two Grid items inside Grid container.

- Grid container should be 100% hight of the screen (or parent container)
- Grig items are large and need to fit container and be scrollable

Pic #1 is what it is, pic #2 is what I need
[image]

so my code is:

```
  "@mui/material": "^5.14.15"
  import { Grid } from '@mui/material';


  <Grid container direction='row' style={{height: '100%', overflow: 'hidden'}}>
    <Grid item xs={6}>
            .......left large content.......
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={6}>
            .......right large content......
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
```

Overflow: 'hidden' makes it look right but content of each Grid item is not scrollable (even I set overflow: 'scroll' for each Grid item). Please advise

Comment: Can you try applying `overflow: auto;` to both the grids. Something like: `<Grid item xs={6} style={{ overflow: 'auto' }}>`

Comment: it has no any effect

Comment: Can you please provide some way to replicate your issue(minimal reproducible example) so that we can try to find the exact solution maybe on https://codesandbox.io/?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-carson-844crh

Answer (score 0):

Well.. since nobody has a solution I fixed it with flexBox:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

alignItems="stretch" on the container might solve it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).